# Polynomial Regression in Azure Machine Learning Studio

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have data that seems to fit a polynomial regression much better than a linear regression, but Azure Machine Learning Studio doesn't have native support for polynomial regressions.  **Is there a way to transform data and produce a web service capable of predicting values that fit this type of data?**

I found a nice [article here](https://vincentlauzon.com/2015/08/05/azureml-polynomial-sql-transformation/) that talks about how to train a model to fit a polynomial regression even though Azure ML doesn't currently natively supports only linear regressions.  The TL;DR of the article calls for adding one or more columns to the data with the square, cube, etc. of the label column in order to improve the accuracy of the model.  That approach has improved my model's coefficient of determination to 0.973346.  However, when I create the "predictive experiment" and the web service to predict new values, and ask the service to predict a new value, the accuracy is horrendous, like not even in the ballpark.

**How can I train a predictive model to data that fits a polynomial regression using Azure Machine Learning Studio?**

Comment: Your polynomial model is probably overfitted. This isn't a programming question, it's a statistics question.